# Is it possible to prevent submit button from submitting until DOM is loaded?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm doing form validation using jquery validate plugin. It works great, however if DOM is not fully loaded and you click submit button then the document ignores validation and goes to a page specified in form "action" attribute. Is it possible to prevent submit button from submitting until DOM is loaded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you generate your submit button like so:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Then you can put this in your `$(document).ready(` right after the validation plugin has been initialised:

```
$("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nZVrs/

Comment: This solution has the drawback, that your form is not usable with out javascript.

Comment: It's also possible to submit a form by pressing ENTER on a text input, so you'd likely need to also disable all inputs in the form too...

Comment: I am hiding form with style display:none and then on docready doing fadeIn.  Also using loading gif.

Answer (score 5):

You could emit your forms initially with something like:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return false;">
....
</form>
```

Then in JavaScript, change the `onsubmit` handlers of the forms you want to "activate" when you're ready.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly would anyone manage to submit a form before `DOMContentLoaded` is fired? Just curious?

If it was `window.onload` we are talking about then I would understand because a page could require some time to load completely (especially if content was not previously cached) but `DOMContentLoaded`?

In most cases it fires so fast after the page starts rendering that its almost impossible to be that fast and submit the form.