# Prevent user from submit button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have got one Kendo UI dropdown box and combobox both are cascading and loading items from DB... and then few more textbox controls and then submit button also....

I made required validation for two textboxes and dropdownList  and we can edit items that we are selected in combobox(we can remove also). Some times user clicks the submit button with out properly loading the items in Combobox then I am getting error like Required validation error ....

Is there any way to **prevent the user from button click until the all the controls are fully loaded** ...

I tried two ways ..

**Approach 1** : i have put button property as hidden and then in combobox **Databound** event made visible the button ... But this approach didn't work..

**Approach 2** :

I have tried the suggestions given in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890136/is-it-possible-to-prevent-submit-button-from-submitting-until-dom-is-loaded)

```
 $("#submit").prop("disabled", false)
```

this approach didn't worked for me..

Is there any other approach to prevent user from clicking the submit button until all controls are loaded...

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: if you want to prevent click you can do this `$("#submit").prop("disabled", true)`, set it to true

Comment: I already tried that that I mention above .....It did not worked for me...

Comment: A form can be submitted by other means than clicking a button. You want to cancel the "submit" event on the form, not the "click" event on the submit button.

Comment: `$("#submit")` what is it? an input button or a customized anchor?

Comment: its a input button not customized one....

Comment: what about disabling it did not work in your case?

Comment: can you add your html-markup or set up an example? (e.g jsFiddle)

Comment: @Tomalak but here I am using ASp.net MVC and this is like createUser form in that case shall we consider the button click event ...

Comment: @aw04 its didnot worked for me my bad....

Comment: well, as @NaeemShaikh pointed out, you have it set to false in your example... was it disabled before that? at what point were you trying to enable it?

Comment: You could make use of a kendoValidator, simply indicating what is required in the html markup, and attach this one to the form, as long as it isn't valid, the submit button won't be enabled. See this link: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/validator

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
<input type='submit' id='submit' value='submit' disabled />
<!--disable the button on default-->
```

and add this js:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", false); // enable it when page loaded.
});
```

<sup>*this solution requires jquery.*</sup>

Comment: @Pluc actually, kendo builds upon jquery, so you are anyhow good :D

Comment: @Icepickle That's what I was about to write until I saw it was specifically tagged jQuery :) Been working with kendo for over 2 years, 40 hours a week. I know!

Answer (score 1):

On some projects i've used the css visibility property to hide show elements at appropriate times: 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

This might be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A display:none style until validation doesn't work for you?

```
$("#submit").css("display", none)
```

or

```
$("#submit").hide()
```